# How to reduce CPU Time Usage with WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, optimization, cpu-usage

[image: CPU time usage]

I have 3 WordPress sites in 1 cPanel account. Since last week, I always exceed the CPU Time Usage limit and it make our site going down and give "Gateway Timeout" for couple times.

Here is what I did so far :

1. Enable dynamic caching
2. Enable gZIP compression with .htaccess
3. Use cloudflare
4. Leverage browser caching with .htaccess
5. Disable wp-cron.php and setup manual cronjob via cPanel
6. Install [Heartbeat Control](https://wordpress.org/plugins/heartbeat-control/) on each site
7. Install [iThemes security](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/) on each site
8. Optimize databases with plugins ([wp-optimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-optimize/) and [wp-sweep](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-sweep/))

All what I did doesn't help.
Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you feel this is malicious then you can activate I'm Under Attack Mode in CloudFlare; this will stop a Layer 7 attack where someone is deliberately trying to exceed your CPU usage.

I would cut down on plugins, trust CloudFlare instead of using iThemes Security, Heartbeat Control, etc.

Also consider switching to a static site generator instead of a WordPress site. Your performance issues look as if they are likely rooted in bad code; try using XDebug to see where the most CPU usage in your code base is at.